# Mongoose 5.3.8 - Can't Extract Geo Keys with MultiLineString and $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson, multilinestring

I am attempting to $push a coordinate pair into a document that contains a GeoJSON MultiLineString that is nested like this: [[[Number]]]

When I findOneAndUpdate like so:

**req.body.point** = [-123.347, 48.43649]

```
Route.findOneAndUpdate({name: req.body.name},
{'$push': { "route.coordinates.0": req.body.point}}, {new: true})
.then(doc => {
    return res.send(doc)
}).catch(err => {
    res.send(err)
})
```

I receive the error message:

```
errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5be9eef393311d2d2c6130fd').......
Point must only contain numeric elements",
"code": 16755,
```

---

My coordinates are valid [long, lat] format as mongo expects. 
is there something I'm missing here?

---

This is my MultiLineString Schema:

```
const MultiLineStringSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['MultiLineString'],
    required: true,
    default: 'MultiLineString'
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [[[Number]]],
    required: true
  }
});
```

This is my route schema:

```
var { MultiLineStringSchema } = require('./GeoJson-Schemas')

const RouteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  route: {
    type: MultiLineStringSchema,
    required: true
  }
});
RouteSchema.index({ route: "2dsphere" });
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the Route document stored that persisted the error. I have re-created the error with this document and have updated the matching _id in the error message above.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5be9eef393311d2d2c6130fd"
    },
    "name": "A Route",
    "route": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -123.3867645,
                    48.4813423
                ],
                [
                    -123.3785248,
                    48.4592626
                ],
                [
                    -123.3766365,
                    48.4527165
                ],
                [
                    -123.3756924,
                    48.4523749
                ],
                [
                    -123.3722591,
                    48.4549366
                ],
                [
                    -123.3704567,
                    48.4559612
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5be9eef393311d2d2c6130fe"
        }
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Moving ahead one step I have added the {_id: false} option to the MultiLineString subdocument and reinitialized a fresh collection. Upon storing the new document like so:

```
{
    "_id": "5be9f076e1caaa23682d80de",
    "name": "A Route",
    "route": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -123.3867645,
                    48.4813423
                ],
                [
                    -123.3785248,
                    48.4592626
                ],
                [
                    -123.3766365,
                    48.4527165
                ],
                [
                    -123.3756924,
                    48.4523749
                ],
                [
                    -123.3722591,
                    48.4549366
                ],
                [
                    -123.3704567,
                    48.4559612
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I attempt to findOneAndUpdate with the exact syntax:

```
Route.findOneAndUpdate({name},
    {'$push': { "route.coordinates.0": point}}, {new: true})
    .then(doc => {
        return res.send(doc)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err)
    })
```

And recive the same error:

```
"errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5be9f076e1caaa23682d80de')...
Point must only contain numeric elements",
"code": 16755,
```

**EDIT 3:**

Moving ahead once more I have updated the RouteSchema **removing** the **subdocument** entirely to be like so:

```
const RouteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  route: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['MultiLineString'],
      required: true,
      default: 'MultiLineString'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [[[Number]]],
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

I store the document like so:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5be9f3915fc64e3548603766"
    },
    "route": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -123.3867645,
                    48.4813423
                ],
                [
                    -123.3785248,
                    48.4592626
                ],
                [
                    -123.3766365,
                    48.4527165
                ],
                [
                    -123.3756924,
                    48.4523749
                ],
                [
                    -123.3722591,
                    48.4549366
                ],
                [
                    -123.3704567,
                    48.4559612
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "name": "A Route",
    "__v": 0
}
```

and FindOneAndUpdate again with the exact syntax, and receive the same error.

```
Route.findOneAndUpdate({name},
    {'$push': { "route.coordinates.0": point}}, {new: true})
    .then(doc => {
        return res.send(doc)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err)
    })


"errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5be9f3915fc64e3548603766')
Point must only contain numeric elements",
"code": 16755,
```

**EDIT 4:**

[mLab hosted instance mongo version 3.6.6 indexes on **Route** collection PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7jdb.png)

Running db.routes.getIndexes() ON shell connection provides the following.

```
 [
            {
                    "v" : 2,
                    "key" : {
                            "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "name" : "_id_",
                    "ns" : "testbench.routes"
            },
            {
                    "v" : 2,
                    "key" : {
                            "route" : "2dsphere"
                    },
                    "name" : "route_2dsphere",
                    "ns" : "testbench.routes",
                    "background" : true,
                    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
            }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show the actual document matching the `_id` given in the error. `ObjectId('5be90afce2b53a23e0f83bda')`. The error message suggests that the data is not stored as you seem to expect it is. Also the `"Point"` in the error message seems to back this up as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn absolutely. I have made some edits above showing how the `RouteSchema` is being stored, the coordinates parameter is the nested array I'm attempting to `$push` into. thank you kindly.

Comment: Okay, but that was not the edit you were asked to make. Your error message says `rrmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5be90afce2b53a23e0f83bda')` So I'm asking you to show **that document** identified by that given `_id` value. Either by showing that document or the unabridged error message, because that is where the problem is. Pretty much as it says with invalid GeoJSON structure.

Comment: Also note that you have `{ route: { type, coordinates, _id } }` since you defined a `Schema` for the sub-document it auto included `_id`, which is also invalid. You should include `{ _id: false }` in the schema definition options or simply inline the field definitions since this is not what separate schema definitions are really for. That **might** be the actual problem here as the error may be referring to the `_id` **within** the `route` sub-document, but providing the whole document actually matching the error given makes it clear.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, of course, my apologies. The data initially provided was on a test stack and has been cleared. I have recreated the error with the exact set-up and have replaced the resulting information according to your instructions, appreciated.

Comment: Go into the shell and do a [`getIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) on the collection. The error seems to indicate you've done something really wrong with an index here.

Comment: @NeilLunn my test db is an mLab hosted instance, I have added a photo of the indexes for the routes collection and the results from `db.routes.getIndexes()` while shelled to the instance, thanks for the effort here.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay but I've been away. What's the content of `point`? At a guess I might say you are attempting to add a "GeoJSON Point" structure to the array, and this breaks the index with the message. You basically should have something resolving to `{ "$push": { "route.coordinates.0": [ -123.3704568, 48.4559612 ] } }` which of course adds the new element with the index present without error.

Comment: As a side note, you might also consider that `MultiLineString` might not be what you really want here and possibly would be better off storing `Point` in separate documents. It depends on what you really intend to do with the data and the question does not go into describing that intent. 9/10 times though people are just pulling GeoJSON from an external source and storing it exactly how they got it, and in most of those cases you were actually better off storing as separate `Point` documents in a collection with some "related" information to the "group".

Comment: Back on topic, the `point` here is more than likely the plausible problem. Since you're using "mongoose", it does some "magic" by comparing your `update()` ( and variants ) statement to the schema and does some type casting. So even if it "looks like an array", things like "strings" for the members might not actually be typecast correctly. Probably an artifact of the `coordinates.0` notation, which does not "strictly" marry up with the nested array structure thus resulting in the `Number` conversion not happening. Manually casting via `parseFloat` should correct that.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hey, yeah no problem I'm at work anyway. the findOneAndUpdate code in mongoose resolves the `point` to `[-123.3701134, 48.4467389]` where the coordinates relate to a long/lat float number and are a point on a sphere. The actual `point` variable in the update code resolves to an array. The idea behinf the MultiLineString schema over something like a Point or a LineString Schema is to be able to push a new "leg" of the route to the first array resulting in two `LineStrings` so a route can end and pick up somewhere else.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have attmepted to manually parse the numbers coming in from the `req.body.point` by assigning the array to a variable and by using `parseFloat(coords[0])` & `parseFloat(coords[1])` then manually feeding the values into an array to be `{'$push': { "route.coordinates.0": [long, lat]}}` pushed into the array and still no luck, the same error persits.

Comment: You might basically try reducing the problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), being a "self contained code listing" which actually reproduces the issue. For "me", simply trying to update with the values you "say" you have and the document you "say" to have does not reproduce the error. An MCVE can at least point to where potential problems are, if not ultimately resolve it by the process of construction. As it stands, I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've re-written the code in an isolated environment using only the two schemas, a fresh database and indexes, and two express routes with all the examples we talked about. The error still seems to persist. If you have a working example I would love to take a look at it, I can't seem to understand the problem or produce a solution. thank for the walkthrough I appreciate it.

Comment: That's alright, I got intrigued and reproduced the issue and solution by myself anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is indeed reproducible and it comes down to the schema definition. Right here:

```
coordinates: {
  type: [[[Number]]],
  required: true
}
```

This is where you are diligently specifying the nested array "rings" required for the `MultiLineString` format of the document. It might seem correct and inserting new documents is not a problem, but pay attention of the notation MongoDB want's here:

```
{ $push: { 'route.coordinates.0': [-123.3701134, 48.4467389] } }
```

So the "schema" has a "double array nest" as in `[[[Number]]]` but MongoDB wants just `coordinates.0` and not `coordinates.0.0` in order to be happy. This is where mongoose gets confused and *"rewrites"* the update statement:

```
{ '$push': { 'route.coordinates.0': [ [ -123.3701134 ], [ 48.4467389 ] ] } }
```

So that's just wrong, and is the source of the error:

> errmsg:
>      'Can\'t extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId(\'5be9f3915fc64e3548603766\'), route: { type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: [ [ [ -123.3867645, 48.4813423 ], [ -123.3785248, 48.4592626 ], [ -123.3766365, 48.4527165 ], [ -123.3756924, 48.4523749 ], [ -123.3722591, 48.4549366 ], [ -123.3704567, 48.4559612 ], [ [ -123.3701134 ], [ 48.4467389 ] ] ] ] }, name: "A Route", __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements',

Altering the schema to not be "so specific" stops mongoose from "mangling" the statement:

```
coordinates: {
  type: []   // Just expect an array without any other definition
  required: true
}
```

Then the update proceeds as expected.

---

For a full reproducible listing:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Sample connection
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/geostring';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// Sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

// Schema defs


const routeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  route: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['MultiLineString'],
      required: true,
      default: 'MultiLineString'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [],
      // type: [[[Number]]], // this has a problem
      required: true
    }
  }
});

routeSchema.index({ route: '2dsphere' });

const Route = mongoose.model('Route', routeSchema);

// log helper
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

// Main
(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean data from all models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert data

    await Route.create({
      "_id": new ObjectId("5be9f3915fc64e3548603766"),
      "name": "A Route",
      "route": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -123.3867645,
              48.4813423
            ],
            [
              -123.3785248,
              48.4592626
            ],
            [
              -123.3766365,
              48.4527165
            ],
            [
              -123.3756924,
              48.4523749
            ],
            [
              -123.3722591,
              48.4549366
            ],
            [
              -123.3704567,
              48.4559612
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    });

    // Test operation

    let result = await Route.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: 'A Route' },
      { $push: { 'route.coordinates.0': [-123.3701134, 48.4467389] } },
      { new: true }
    );
    log(result);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

And the "correct" output from corrected schema:

```
Mongoose: routes.createIndex({ route: '2dsphere' }, { background: true })
Mongoose: routes.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: routes.insertOne({ route: { type: 'MultiLineString', coordinates: [ [ [ -123.3867645, 48.4813423 ], [ -123.3785248, 48.4592626 ], [ -123.3766365, 48.4527165 ], [ -123.3756924, 48.4523749 ], [ -123.3722591, 48.4549366 ], [ -123.3704567, 48.4559612 ] ] ] }, _id: ObjectId("5be9f3915fc64e3548603766"), name: 'A Route', __v: 0 })
Mongoose: routes.findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'A Route' }, { '$push': { 'route.coordinates.0': [ -123.3701134, 48.4467389 ] } }, { upsert: false, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "route": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -123.3867645,
          48.4813423
        ],
        [
          -123.3785248,
          48.4592626
        ],
        [
          -123.3766365,
          48.4527165
        ],
        [
          -123.3756924,
          48.4523749
        ],
        [
          -123.3722591,
          48.4549366
        ],
        [
          -123.3704567,
          48.4559612
        ],
        [
          -123.3701134,
          48.4467389
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "_id": "5be9f3915fc64e3548603766",
  "name": "A Route",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the insights, Niel, it works great. Appreciate all your help today.